# Simple custom model validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to do two simple custom validations:

```
if project.end < project.start, raise an exception.
if project.start, set project.active to equal true
```

My code (probably horribly noobishly incorrect) isn't working:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_data # now changed to before_validation

  def check_data
     if end < start
         errors.add(:base, 'Project end date must be after project start date.')
     end
     if start
         active = true
     end
  end
```

The error is being added **but** but I am not being circled back to the form with an error message - on the user side it seems that everything is fine.

Also, the field `active` is not changing in the database.

---

Controller code:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
    redirect_to home_url   
else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your form."
    redirect_to edit_project_url
end
```

---

### Update - How do you change a field from the model?

I changed the above code to before_validation, but the `active` field **is still not** being changed in the database. How can I make the above model code work?

#### Answer: Use `self.active`.

Comment: Can you post your controller code for the controller calling project.save ?  I assume this is either ProjectsController#update or ProjectsController#create (or both).  Either way, including the controller code may help figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Side note: I would recommend using `errors.add_to_base(...` instead of `errors.add(:base, ...`. Either will work for now, but the second uses rails internals that might change in the future.

Comment: @Ben - I got a 'Rails deprecated' warning when I first used `errors.add_to_base`.

Comment: @sscirrus, you're right. I had it backwards =).

Comment: Are you really using an attribute named `end`? I don't suppose that would work.

Comment: @Adam - I'm not. I shortened it from the real name for this question.

Comment: @Brett Bender - I've posted the controller code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the error condition to work right, use `before_validation` instead of `before_save`.

The success condition isn't working right because the `active` assignment there is a local variable, not a model attribute. You must explicitly use "self" here like `self.active = true`.

Comment: if before_validate works then why would using `before_save` make my code non-functional?

Comment: @sscirrus, you don't want it to get past the validation stage without having run your custom validation. An object will still save even if it has errors on it. So in the above, it will correctly validate even if "e < s", then it will start the save process, add an error to the base, but save anyway because the error doesn't matter. Not sure if the active not saving is related -- it might be a separate problem. In any case, I'd change the `before_save` to `before_validation` first, make sure the error path is now correctly working, then check up on the success path.

Comment: I changed to @before_validate but the `active` field is not updating in the database. My logger is showing that the code is running, but the console is not displaying any changes.

Comment: @sscirrus -- The `active` variable is not being set because you are setting a local variable, not a model attribute. You must explicitly use "self" here like `self.active = true`.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use `before_validation` if you're validating. The reasoning is that if you have other validations which fail, your check_data will never run and therefore a user will never see those errors.  This could lead to a situation where they enter project data, get a validation error, fix that error, and then your check_data runs and tells them about another validation error.  If you use before_validation then they will see all the errors at once.

I don't know if that will actually fix the bug you're experiencing with active not saving, but the bug you noticed about errors not showing up in the form is due to your use of `redirect_to edit_project_url` - you should probably use

```
render :edit
```

from your update action and

```
render :new
```

from your create action.  `errors` is actually part of the `@project` object, so when you redirect (instead of render) to the new action, a new object is created.  When you redirect to the edit page, the existing object is loaded from the database. This is how your errors array is disappearing.  If you render instead of redirect, your errors will remain on the object and display in your view (assuming you have all that set up correctly).

Hope that helps, good luck figuring out the active state issue!

Comment: Very helpful Brett, thanks! I am still trying to get the model to change the `active` field from false to true before validating (if `start` contains anything).